# 2 child components infinitely re rendering eachother

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components and i know that the problem is that they are infinitely re rendering each other, but how can I do this a different way? When the 'Subs' component is rendered, it renders the scopesheet component. When scopesheet is rendered, I need to re render the Subs component because it forms sort of a popup. How else can I go about doing this?

Subs component -

```
const Subs = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)((props) => { 

const { project, section, bid, bidId } = props;


return (
<>

<div>other things</div>

<Scopesheet
          
          bidId={bidId}
          bid={bid}
          section={section}
          project={project}
         
        />
</>
)


})

export default Subs;
```

Scopesheet component -

```
function Scopesheet(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const canvasWrapper = useRef();

  const {
    section,
    bid,
    bidId,
    project,
   
    
  } = props;

  const subUI = useMemo(() => {
    const subsArray = [];

    subsArray.push(
      <Subs key={bidId} section={section} bid={bid} project={project} />
    );

    return (<div>{subArray}</div>);

  }, [section, bid, project, bidId]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={canvasWrapper} className={classes.scopesheetCanvasWrapper}>

        {subUI}

        <canvas style={{ float: 'right' }} ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
      </div>
     

    </>
  );
}

export default Scopesheet;
```

I am passing important information from Subs to Scopesheet such as bidId and props that I need from it to preform different actions, but within scopesheet I need to be able to render the Subs component again to form the popup. Is there a way I can do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Having components as children of eachother will give you nothing but that kind of performance.
I strongly suggest you use a form of callback Props to update your `subs`. And remove the useMemo along with the subs from the Scopesheet component.
Now add a new prop to Scopesheet in subs like so...

```
<Scopesheet
          
          bidId={bidId}
          bid={bid}
          section={section}
          project={project}
          cb={cbFunction} 
         
        />
```

And the cbFunction should require these args

```
function cbFunction(bidId,bid,section,project) {
// update your state through here
}
```

Advise: consider using `useState` hooks or `useReducer` to manage your state.

**Updated:**

> I'm having a hard time understanding what the use of cbFunction exactly is. I'm not updating state in either component, so I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Is there a way I can render the scopesheet component inside subs only one time? Basically, there is a container with information called subs, and in subs I render scopesheet and in scopesheet I have buttons and on click of those buttons causes a popup which I then need to render the subs container again inside the popup, but this is causing an infinite loop. Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question.

1. *Is there a way I can render the scopesheet component inside subs only one time?*

*If the information/data in subs are mutable, it will still cause scopesheet to re-render, depending on how you handle the data.* you may check `useRef` if you don't want change in the data to re-render your scopesheet.

2. *in scopesheet I have buttons and on click of those buttons causes a popup which I then need to render the subs container again inside the popup, but this is causing an infinite loop.*

as stated earlier, infinite loop is inevitable if you have the sub container as a child of scopesheet again. a simple way around it is to make use of [material-ui modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/). set a new DOM_Node and with some pure js and css style your pop-up. you may refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@daniela.sandoval/creating-a-popup-window-using-js-and-react-4c4bd125da57).
if my answer is still not clear enough, you may try and supply more snippet of your implementation code and state more coherently what you're trying to acheive. other stachoverflowers might be able to give a answer to it.

**Happy coding...**

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the use of cbFunction exactly is. I'm not updating state in either component, so I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  Is there a way I can render the scopesheet component inside subs only one time? Basically, there is a container with information called subs, and in subs I render scopesheet and in scopesheet I have buttons and on click of those buttons causes a popup which I then need to render the subs container again inside the popup, but this is causing an infinite loop. Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question.